# How to use javascript in PHP class functions?

Tags: php, javascript, oop, class

As you see I have class whose name is table; and I have many functions on it "mainface" is one of them; these function is like my interface there are some check box and combobox on it; I want to write some JavaScript on "All" checkbox `-> onclick=" "`.
I want that when the user click on the "All" checkbox and option will disappear on the screen but I cannot find a way to do it.
Is there any way to do it ? Can I add call the JavaScript function to onclick?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function hide(){
            if(document.form.All.checked){
                 document.getElementById('option').style.visibility="hidden";
            }
}
</script>

</head>
<body> 

<?php

class table{

   public function   __construct() {
       echo table:: mainface();              
   }

   public function mainface()
   {
      $arayuz=" ";
      $arayuz.="<form name=form action=index.php method=post>";
      $arayuz.="<fieldset>";

    $arayuz.="<input type=checkbox name=All value=All onclick='SOME JAVA SCRIPT FUNCTION'>;

}
?>
```

Comment: Although this may look like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545167/how-to-run-javascript-function-into-php-class-function, it's not, the older question was edited after it got closed.

Comment: Yes it is duplicate my older one is seems to very confuse ;now ı make clear my questions and make commmnet on it tobe understandable

Comment: LAmureTJ: Write your HTML and Javascript first: this is what the browser sees. _Then_, write your PHP around it: this is pre-processed and helps you to automatically generate your HTML and Javascript; at this stage, do not touch your HTML or Javascript.

Comment: That's looking much better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php file:

```
public function mainface()
{
    $output = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/path_to_your_js/table.js\">-</script>";
    $output.= "<form name =\"form\" action=\"index.php\" method=\"POST\">";
    $output.= "<fieldset>";
    $output.= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ALL\" value=\"ALL\" onclick=\"checkAll(this)\">";
}
```

And then in table.js:

```
function checkAll( myCheckBox )
{
    //do some stuff you need here
    myCheckBox.style.display = "none";
}
```

I hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing server side and client side script languages. PHP runs server side (on the web server), javascript runs client side (within the web browser). Onclick is javascript, so runs client side. You cannot call PHP functions directly from an Onclick action.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side

To achieve what you want you don't need any PHP scripting. It can all be done in Javascript. You'll need to add an ID to your form like this:

```
$arayuz.="<form name='form' id='myform' action='index.php' method='post'>";
```

Then use the following as the onclick action:

```
$arayuz.="<input type=checkbox name=All value=All onclick='document.getElementById(\"myform\").style.visibility = \"hidden\";'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

That would work but printing out in-line JavaScript like that is hideous, I would really recommend you look into unobtrusive JavaScript and use something like jQuery. Jquery example that would work for all checkbox's:

`$(":checkbox").live('click' , function () {
   $("#IdOfForm").hide();
});`

Answer (score 0):

form id is used in onclick

```
  $arayuz.="<form name='form' id='form1' action='index.php' method='post'>";
```

this will be your onclick

```
  $arayuz.="<input type=checkbox name=All value=All onclick='document.getElementById(\"form1\").style.visibility = \"hidden\";'>"
```